# Transform string in key variable name

Tags: elm

There is the possibility of converting a string to a key, eg:

```
type alias Model =
  { sun : Int  -- Init with 0
  , moon : Int -- Init with 0
  }
```

What I want to achieve:

```
let
  userSelect = "sun";
in
 ({ model | userSelect = 1 }, Cmd.none)  -- ugly to be easy to understand
```

After model.sun should 1

Comment: It might help to have a bit more detail about what you're trying to achieve with your model - are you choosing between items or doing a multiple select or something different

Comment: Hi, have you been able to make progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do exactly what you want as access to records does not work that way. In your case i would recommend a Dictionary

```
type alias Model =
  { planets : Dict String Int
  }


planets = 
    Dict.fromList 
        [ ("sun", 0)
        , ("moon": 0)
        ]
model = { planets = planets }
```

and then

```
let
  userSelect = "sun";
in
 ({ model | planets = Dict.insert userSelect 1 model.planets }, Cmd.none)
```

Comment: I was sick and could not enter again. As my project is already giant, it does not have time to remake the structures. However, his response served very well. Thank you.

Comment: Hope you are feeling better